# Sum first occurence of value from two columns in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df1

Category    Year    cat_counts
43  5.0 1988    1
44  1.0 1987    4
45  3.0 1987    3
46  3.0 1987    3
47  1.0 1987    4
48  2.0 1985    2
49  3.0 1985    3
50  1.0 1983    4
51  1.0 1983    4
52  2.0 1982    2
53  4.0 1980    1

df2


Category    Year    cat_counts
91  2.0 1989    6
92  2.0 1989    6
93  1.0 1988    10
94  2.0 1988    6
95  1.0 1987    10
96  2.0 1987    6
97  1.0 1987    10
98  1.0 1987    10
99  5.0 1985    2
100 1.0 1985    10
101 2.0 1985    6
102 4.0 1985    1
103 5.0 1985    2
104 1.0 1983    10
105 2.0 1983    6
106 1.0 1983    10
107 1.0 1982    10
108 1.0 1982    10
109 3.0 1982    1
110 1.0 1981    10
```

The column 'cat_counts' counts the frequency of a category and then associates that frequency with the category where it occurred. For example, in df1, there are 4 instances of 'Category' = 1, so the associated 'cat_counts'=4 and is applied anywhere the 'Category'=1.

Now, I want to add the values in 'cat_count' together for the two dfs, but I only want to keep one instance of the value in 'Category' and it's associated 'cat_count'.

My expected output would look something like this for this example:

```
Category   cat_counts
1          11
2          8
3          4
4          2
5          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` then `value_counts`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])['Category'].value_counts()
1.0    14
2.0     8
3.0     4
5.0     3
4.0     2
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```